# How to get Node component in linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Learnt how to [reverse-a-linked-list](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/reverse-a-linked-list/). The link is very descriptive and clear. But somehow I'm not getting how to get the Node component which needs to be passed to below method. I did not find any method under [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
to get the Node.
Sorry for asking dumb question but everywhere on net, it's assumed we have the Node component, and then program starts from there

```java
public void recursiveReverse(Node currentNode ){
    ...
}
```

Comment: The link you posted is about implementing your own linked list data structure, and your own reverse function. Not about using the standard Java LinkedList class, which uses nodes internally, but doesn't expose them.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to write your own LinkedList class from scratch to implement that method. `java.util.LinkedList` doesn't expose its internal implementation. For example, the nodes are called entries instead, and that class, `java.util.LinkedList.Entry`, is private.